# Tikz UML State Text not working

Tags: tikz-uml

I wanted to use the *umlstatetext* macro in my uml state diagram. I use the version 1.0 of tikz-uml though the macro just does nothing, as in there is no text added in the body of the state or any where else.
Anybody with similar problems and knows a work around?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlstate}[x=0,y=-4, name=horizontal, fill=white]{Waagrecht}
\umlstatetext{Some State Content}
\end{umlstate}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: In this example it works actually. But as soon as the example gets more complicated it just doesn't show it anymore:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlstate}[name=main]{Großkanonischer-Monte-Carlo-Schritt}
\umlstateinitial[x=4, y=1.75, name=mainInit]
\begin{umlstate}[y=-2, name=input, fill=gray!20]{\shortstack{Einfügen\\ Wahrscheinlichkeit $\alpha_{ins} = \frac{2M^2}{N+1}\cdot e^{\beta \cdot }$}}
\umlstateinitial[x = 4, name=initInput]
\begin{umlstate}[x=0,y=-4, name=horizontal, fill=white]{Waagrecht}
\umlstatetext{Some

State

Content

$$x = y$$
}
\umlstatetext{Teste auf Kollision}

\umlstatedecision[x=4, y=0, name=decision]
\umlstatefinal[x=1, y=-3, name=collision]
\umlHVtrans[arg=transition1, pos=1.5]{decision}{collision}
\begin{umlstate}[x=4, y=-3, name=noCollision]{Keine Kollision}
\end{umlstate}
\umltrans[arg=]{decision}{noCollision}
\end{umlstate}
\begin{umlstate}[x=8,y=-4, name=vertical, fill=white]{Senkrecht}
\umlstatedecision[ x=4, y=0, name=decision]
\begin{umlstate}[x=1, y=-3, name=noCollision]{Keine Kollision}
\end{umlstate}
\umlbasicstate[x=4.5, y=-3, name=collision]{Kollision}
\end{umlstate}
\umlHVtrans[arg=transition1, pos=1.5]{initInput}{vertical}
\umlHVtrans[arg=transition1, pos=1.5]{initInput}{horizontal}
\end{umlstate}
\umlHVtrans[arg=$\frac{1}{2}$, pos=1.5]{mainInit}{input}
\end{umlstate}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, seems there can be only one `\umlstatetext` in an `umlstate` environment, any additional ones will overwrite the first one. And the text in the argument is put inside a `tabular` with a single `l` column, so text doesn't wrap, and you can't use displayed math. You can add multiple lines by using `\\` though, as in a normal `tabular`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlstate}[x=0,y=-4, name=horizontal, fill=white]{Waagrecht}
\umlstatetext{%
Some State Content\\
And more}
\end{umlstate}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of above code]

Regarding your more complex example, if you have a nested `umlstate` environment, you need to add the `\umlstatetext` *after* the nested environment. This is, if I understood the code directly, because `\umlstatetext` does

```
\def\tikzumlStateText{#1}
```

but the `umlstate` environment does

```
\def\tikzumlStateText{tikzumlEmpty}%
```

before the content of the environment, i.e. it "empties" the existing definition of `\tikzumlStateText`.

So implementing that in your larger example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}    
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlstate}[name=main]{Großkanonischer-Monte-Carlo-Schritt}
\umlstateinitial[x=4, y=1.75, name=mainInit]
\begin{umlstate}[y=-2, name=input, fill=gray!20]{\shortstack{Einfügen\\ Wahrscheinlichkeit $\alpha_{ins} = \frac{2M^2}{N+1}\cdot e^{\beta \cdot }$}}
\umlstateinitial[x = 4, name=initInput]
\begin{umlstate}[x=0,y=-4, name=horizontal, fill=white]{Waagrecht}
\umlstatedecision[x=4, y=0, name=decision]
\umlstatefinal[x=1, y=-3, name=collision]
\umlHVtrans[arg=transition1, pos=1.5]{decision}{collision}
\begin{umlstate}[x=4, y=-3, name=noCollision]{Keine Kollision}
\end{umlstate}
% note this is placed after the nested umlstate environment
\umlstatetext{Teste auf Kollision}
\umltrans[arg=]{decision}{noCollision}
\end{umlstate}
\begin{umlstate}[x=8,y=-4, name=vertical, fill=white]{Senkrecht}
\umlstatedecision[ x=4, y=0, name=decision]
\begin{umlstate}[x=1, y=-3, name=noCollision]{Keine Kollision}
\end{umlstate}
\umlbasicstate[x=4.5, y=-3, name=collision]{Kollision}
\end{umlstate}
\umlHVtrans[arg=transition1, pos=1.5]{initInput}{vertical}
\umlHVtrans[arg=transition1, pos=1.5]{initInput}{horizontal}
\end{umlstate}
\umlHVtrans[arg=$\frac{1}{2}$, pos=1.5]{mainInit}{input}
\end{umlstate}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of second code]